# Ways of packaging up a custom DLL with 3rd Party exe

Tags: c#, dll, package, exe

I'm curious to know how to wrap up some 3rd party exe files into my dll for deployment.

At the moment we rely on the deployed system having the 3rd party software installed and our wrapper exposes their console app to our MVC application.

Ideally I'd like the wrapper and the exe's all packaged up together in a nice bundle that can be deployed anywhere regardless of the 3rd party app being installed.

Any advice on where to store the exe files in my application would also be really helpful. I'm curently dropping them into the bin.

I'm aware that licencing can be an issue here and it's something I'm already ontop of.

Comment: Writing your own installer that puts stuff anywhere you need them and is just a single setup.exe file is not difficult.  What is the real problem here?

Comment: I'm creating a wrapper dll that I'd like to make publically available. Ideally the user of the dll won't have to have the 3rd party software installed. I realise I can distribute my dll with the 3rd party software, I just wondered if it's possible to combine it all into my single dll to make things easy for the consuming user.

Comment: The consuming user must be able to use the dll from a web application, without the necessity to install things on their hosting server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "packaging" you mean including the .exe file in your dll? I mean you could of course include the .exe file into your setup package, but that's not what you want if I understand correctly.

I believe starting a .exe file which does not physically exist ist not possible in windows. But you could include the .exe file as a ressource into your .dll.... possibly in a compressed form. When you need it, it could be dropped into a temporary directory, executed, and deleted after use or on dll uninitialization.

However this technique *could* maybe alert some security software...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've decided to deploy the 3rd party app alongside my dll. It seems like an unnecessary amount of effort to include the exe's (there's about 10) in the dll itself.